# How can I filter & route messages using Headers Exchange with Spring AMQP & Rabbit?

Tags: spring, filter, rabbitmq, message

Using Spring AMQP when I use the headers exchange, all messages get sent to the queue irrespective of header content. To be more specific, I declare in the xml that I only want messages with "betty rubble" in the headers but non-matching messages still come through. What am I doing wrong?
I would like to be able to do it programmatically too so I've also tried using the BindingBuilder class but had no joy there either. There don't seem to be any examples of headers exchanges with spring amqp or examples with the BindingBuilder.

I have successfully routed/filtered using these headers with java & plain rabbit api but Spring offers some elegant wrapping I'd like to use.

I'm using Spring Core 3.2.2.RELEASE, Spring AMQP 1.1.4.RELEASE, RabbitMq 3.0.4 and not using Spring Integration.
Here's my code in the form of a test (may get to assert something one day :-)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-test-rabbit.xml" })
public class SpringRabbitTest  {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private HeadersExchange headersExchange;
    @Autowired
    private MessageConverter converter;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mymessage.consumer")
    private Queue consumerQ;


    @Test
    public void headersTest() throws InterruptedException  {

            MessageProperties messageProperties = new MessageProperties();
            messageProperties.setHeader("fred", "flintstone"); 
            messageProperties.setHeader("wilma", "flintstone");
            messageProperties.setHeader("barney", "rubble");   

            MyMessage myMessage = new MyMessage("just an example");
            Message message = converter.toMessage(myMessage, messageProperties);

            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(headersExchange.getName(),"", message);

            Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

app Ctx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.1.xsd" >

    <context:component-scan base-package="uk.co.abc" />

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" username="guest" password="guest" virtual-host="/" port="5672" />

    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter"/>

    <rabbit:template connection-factory="connectionFactory" id="amqpTemplate" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"/>

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:queue id="mymessage.consumer" name="mymessage.consumer"/>

    <rabbit:headers-exchange name="headers.mymessage.all" id="headers.mymessage.all" >
        <rabbit:bindings >
            <rabbit:binding queue="mymessage.consumer" key="betty" value="rubble"   /> 
            <!-- <rabbit:binding queue="mymessage.consumer" key="fred" value="flintstone" /> --> 
            <!-- <rabbit:binding queue="mymessage.consumer" key="barney" value="rubble"   /> --> 
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:headers-exchange>



    <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" error-handler="loggingErrorHandler">
        <rabbit:listener queues="mymessage.consumer" ref="myMessageHandler" method="handleMyMessage" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>


</beans>
```

message bean

```
package uk.co.abc;

public class MyMessage {

    private String message;

    public MyMessage() {
    }


    public MyMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyMessage [message=" + message + "]";
    }

}
```

handler

```
package uk.co.abc;                                                                                                                                                                      

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;                                                                                                                                                  
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;                                                                                                                                           
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;                                                                                                                          
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;                                                                                                                                        

@Component                                                                                                                                                                              
@Qualifier("myMessageHandler")                                                                                                                                                          
public class MyMessageHandler {                                                                                                                                                         


    public void handleMyMessage(MyMessage myMessage) {                                                                                                                                  
        System.out.println("Got it! "  + myMessage);                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                             }
```

and for completeness, the pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                                http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <spring.amqp.version>1.1.4.RELEASE</spring.amqp.version>
        <rabbitmq.version>3.0.4</rabbitmq.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.5.2</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-erlang</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>${rabbitmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The debug log implies the exchange doesn't have the headers set

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory] - Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate] - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin] - declaring Exchange 'headers.mymessage.all'
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin] - declaring Queue 'mymessage.consumer'
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin] - Binding destination [mymessage.consumer (QUEUE)] to exchange [headers.mymessage.all] with routing key []
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin] - Declarations finished
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer] - Started on queue 'mymessage.consumer': Consumer: tag=[null], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer] - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[null], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory] - Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2)
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate] - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2)
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate] - Publishing message on exchange [headers.mymessage.all], routingKey = []
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer] - Storing delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-JS6zwiLjp6cGSNbieRTlvw], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer] - Received message: (Body:'{"message":"just an example"}'; ID:null; Content:application/json; Headers:{wilma=flintstone, fred=flintstone, __TypeId__=uk.co.abc.MyMessage, barney=rubble}; Exchange:headers.mymessage.all; RoutingKey:; Reply:null; DeliveryMode:PERSISTENT; DeliveryTag:1)
Got it! MyMessage [message=just an example]
```

Comment: See my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489301/only-consuming-messages-with-certain-headers-using-rabbitmq-and-springamqp

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you do not use headers routing, it's performance is horrible compared to Topic and Pivotal themselves have said not to use it.

http://techblog.betgenius.com/performance-tuning-our-rabbitmq-routing-strategy/