# Only consuming messages with certain headers using RabbitMQ and SpringAMQP

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to publish a message to a queue and then have certain consumers consume it only if it contains a certain header and another consumer consume it if it contains another header.

What I've done so far is to setup a headers-exchange that routes messages to a certain queue only if it contains that header.

[image]

This is the config I'm using to setup the exchange and the queue and the listener:

```
<!-- Register Queue Listener Beans -->
<bean id="ActionMessageListener" class="com.mycee.Action" />    

<!-- Register RabbitMQ Connections -->
<rabbit:connection-factory 
    id="connectionFactory"
    port="${rabbit.port}"
    virtual-host="${rabbit.virtual}" 
    host="${rabbit.host}" 
    username="${rabbit.username}"
    password="${rabbit.password}" 
    connection-factory="nativeConnectionFactory" />

<!-- Register RabbitMQ Listeners -->
<rabbit:listener-container          
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    channel-transacted="true"
    requeue-rejected="true"
    concurrency="${rabbit.consumers}">
    <rabbit:listener queues="${queue.myqueue}" ref="ActionMessageListener" method="handle"/>        
</rabbit:listener-container>    

<!-- Setup RabbitMQ headers exchange -->
<rabbit:headers-exchange id="${exchange.myexchange}" name="${exchange.myexchange}">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="${queue.myqueue}" key="action" value="action3" />            
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:headers-exchange>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>  
<rabbit:queue name="${queue.myqueue}" />
```

So I'm binding myqueue to myexchange using key of action and value of action3.

Now when I publish on the exchange:

[image]

the ChannelAwareMessageListener is consuming it even though the action was set to action1 instead of action3

```
public class Action implements ChannelAwareMessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(message.toString());

    }

}
```

Either I'm not using a headers-exchange correctly or I'm not configuring it correctly - any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way; you need a separate queue for each consumer. See [the tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html).

When multiple consumers consume from the same queue they compete for all messages; you can't select messages on the consumer side; the "selection" is done by the exchange by routing messages to specific queue(s).

Comment: Ok, just to confirm what I've learned today, doesn't matter if I'm using header, topic, direct or fanout exchanges, all these exchanges are doing is routing messages to a queue. If I have a 100 consumers each consuming a different action, I should have a 100 queues named action00 to action99 instead of routing all of them to "myqueue" as in the above question. Furthermore, there's no way to consume a message from a queue based on certain paramaters (you always get the first one) or directly bind to an exchange and consume directly from an exchange, exchanges' purpose is to route to a queue.

Comment: Just to cement this idea, if I were doing an RPC call from a publisher via a fanout exchange and let's say the message is fanned out to 10 queues, consumed by 10 consumers and then they all respond, would the first response be consumed and the rest just hang in limbo until they timeout?

Comment: Yes (to all in first comment). Second comment - it depends on how you configure your replyTo but essentially, yes, all consumers can respond. The difficulty is knowing how many replies to consume (you'd have to know how many consumers you expect to reply). You would also have to correlate the replies somehow. One simple way to achieve both would be to declare a temporary auto-delete queue for the replies and listen to it until some timeout occurs. There's no out-of-the-box support for such a scenario in Spring-AMQP but it wouldn't be difficult to roll your own, using `RabbitTemplate.execute()`