# RabbitMQ, headers exchange, messages not routed by headers x-match = all

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm trying to setup a headers exchange with a queue where messages are routed based on a recipient header.

The exchange is of type headers.

So far the class is able to connect to the exchange and feed messages to the queue.
It's also able to subscribe to the queue and receive messages. It also closes the connection whenever the subscriber's connection is cancelled.

The current problem is that the message is not routed by the recipient's header value.

Given the following class:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

@Slf4j
public class MyQueue {

private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
private Channel channel;


public MyQueue(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
}

public String sendMessage(TestTextMessage message) throws UndeliverableMessageException {
    try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
         Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {

        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put(RabbitMqConfig.MATCH_HEADER, message.getRecipient());
        AMQP.BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
                .deliveryMode(MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN.getDeliveryMode())
                .priority(MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN.getPriority())
                .headers(headers).build();

        log.info("Sending message to {}", headers);

        channel.basicPublish(RabbitMqConfig.EXCHANGE_NAME, "", props,
                message.getMessage().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        log.info("RabbitMQ sent message {} to {}", message.getMessage(), message.getRecipient());
        return "ok";
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        log.error("Rabbit mq timeout", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Rabbit mq io error", e);
    }
    throw new UndeliverableMessageException();
}

public Flux<String> listenMessages(String recipient) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
    this.channel = connection.createChannel();

    // The map for the headers.
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("x-match", "all");
    headers.put(RabbitMqConfig.MATCH_HEADER, recipient);

    final String[] consumerTag = new String[1];
    Flux<String> as = Flux.create(sink -> new MessageListener<String>() {
        {
            try {
                log.info("Binding to {}", headers);
                channel.queueBind(RabbitMqConfig.QUEUE_NAME, RabbitMqConfig.EXCHANGE_NAME, "",
                        headers);
                DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
                    String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    log.info("Subscriber {} received a message {} with headers {}", recipient, delivery.getEnvelope(),
                            delivery.getProperties().getHeaders());

                    sink.next(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag() + "--" + message);
                    //channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
                };

                consumerTag[0] = channel.basicConsume(RabbitMqConfig.QUEUE_NAME,
                        true, deliverCallback, tag -> {
                            sink.complete();
                        });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("RabbitMQ IOException ", e);
            }
        }

    });

    return as.doOnCancel(() -> {
        try {
            if (consumerTag[0] == null) {
                log.error("RabbitMQ uncloseable subscription, consumerTag is null!");
                channel.close();
                return;
            }
            channel.basicCancel(consumerTag[0]);
            channel.close();
            log.info("RabbitMQ CANCEL subscription for recipient {}", recipient);
        } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
            log.error("RabbitMQ channel close error", e);
        }
    });
}

interface MessageListener<T> {

}
}
```

The exchange is declared by the following call

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(RabbitMqConfig.EXCHANGE_NAME, BuiltinExchangeType.HEADERS, true);
```

Binding recipient log:

```
Binding to {x-match=all, message-recipient=mary}
Binding to {x-match=all, message-recipient=james}
Binding to {x-match=all, message-recipient=john}
```

Bound 3 recipients with x-match:
[image: Bound 3 recipients]

However, messages are not matched, as if they were routed randomly

```
Sending message to {message-recipient=james}
RabbitMQ sent message Hey there to james
Subscriber mary received a message Envelope(deliveryTag=1, redeliver=false, exchange=my-exchange, routingKey=) with headers {message-recipient=james}

Sending message to {message-recipient=james}
RabbitMQ sent message Hey there to james
Subscriber james received a message Envelope(deliveryTag=1, redeliver=false, exchange=my-exchange, routingKey=) with headers {message-recipient=james}

Sending message to {message-recipient=james}
RabbitMQ sent message Hey there to james
Subscriber john received a message Envelope(deliveryTag=1, redeliver=false, exchange=my-exchange, routingKey=) with headers {message-recipient=james}
```

Why isn't `x-match: all`, matching?

Comment: I've only used RabbitMQ in a very surface-level sense, but can you provide the exchange declaration code?

Comment: @Gryphon Sure, I've added the call to the question

Comment: So from what I see in the docs and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489301/only-consuming-messages-with-certain-headers-using-rabbitmq-and-springamqp), RabbitMQ won't filter messages by header on the consumer side. Header bindings are used to route (instead of routing key) to different queues. So you would need to make a queue for mary, a queue for james, and a queue for john. The Server would route to the queues based on the header and the consumers would read from their individual queues.

Comment: Alright, tested it that way, it works as intended by routing based on the recipient match. I thought the routing would be taking place at the queue level, but it actually takes place at the exchange level, if you provide a code snippet, i can mark your answer as accepted

Comment: If you already have the test snippet, go ahead and post that (especially if it works for you) and accept as your own answer. As I don't have a way to test it at the moment, it's better if it's correct than just a guess from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comment posted by @Gryphon, on the subscriber side, I ended up creating a queue for each participant.

```
channel.queueDeclare(RabbitMqConfig.QUEUE_NAME + "-" + recipient,
    true,
    false,
    false,
    null)
```

On the publisher side, code remains unchanged, the messages are sent to the exchange, and the exchange will handle routing based on the `x-match: all` configuration, routing the messages to the appropiate queue.